# Prompt boxes - current date format

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to work with 3 prompt boxes to produce a current date. The 3 prompt boxes go with full day or short day? , full month or short month?  and 2-digit or 4-digit year?

Once the prompts are filled out the possible outcomes would be (the current date) with the the options they select in the prompt boxes.

So far I have this. The 3 prompts and some arrays with the selections

```
var day  = (prompt ("Full day or short day? ", ""));
var month =(prompt("Full month or short month?", ""));
var year =(prompt("2-digit year or 4-digit year?", ""));
var theday = new Date();
var day = theday.getDay();


daylong = [];
daylong[0] = "Sunday";
daylong[1] = "Monday";
daylong[2] = "Tuesday";
daylong[3] = "Wednesday";
daylong[4] = "Thursday";
daylong[5] = "Friday";
daylong[6] = "Saturday";

alert(daylong[5]);

dayshort = [];
dayshort[0] = "Sun";
dayshort[1] = "Mon";
dayshort[2] = "Tue";
dayshort[3] = "Wed";
dayshort[4] = "Thu";
dayshort[5] = "Fri";
dayshort[6] = "Sat";



monthlong = [];
monthlong[0] = "January";
monthlong[1] = "February";
monthlong[2] = "March";
monthlong[3] = "April";
monthlong[4] = "May";
monthlong[5] = "June";
monthlong[6] = "July";
monthlong[7] = "August";
monthlong[8] = "September";
monthlong[9] = "October";
monthlong[10] = "November";
monthlong[11] = "December";

alert(monthlong[8]);

monthshort = [];
monthshort[0] = "Jan";
monthshort[1] = "Feb";
monthshort[2] = "Mar";
monthshort[3] = "Apr";
monthshort[5] = "Jun";
monthshort[6] = "Jul";
monthshort[7] = "Aug";
monthshort[8] = "Sept";
monthshort[9] = "Oct";
monthshort[10] = "Nov";
monthshort[11] = "Dec";

document.write(dayshort[day] + daylong[day]);
```

Comment: What's your question exactly?

Comment: @m0meni how to get the result such as Monday, February 18, 2017

Mon, February 18, 2017
Monday, Feb 18, 2017
Mon, February 18, 17   ... but in today's date. With the inputs from the prompt boxes.

Comment: Still not getting what will you pass in prompt

Comment: @SourabhSomani sorry I'm pretty new to JS and may not understand your question. I am trying to have it so once I fill out the 3 prompt boxes I get the outcome of today's date.  The output will depend on my choices of the prompt boxes. So there will be a combination of 4 possible date formats based on my selections.

Answer (score 0):

I understand what you are trying to do, but there may be a simpler way. The [`moment.js` package](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.js) is a very flexible package for handling `Date` objects in JavaScript.

Using this package, depending on the choices from the alert boxes, you can configure a format expression, as demonstrated below.

```js
var formats = {
  day: {
    short: 'ddd',
    long: 'dddd'
  },
  month: {
    short: 'MMM',
    long: 'MMMM'
  },
  year: {
    short: 'YY',
    long: 'YYYY'
  }
};

var day_format = prompt('Choose a format for the day. (short or long)') == 'short' ? formats.day.short : formats.day.long;

var month_format = prompt('Choose a format for the month. (short or long)') == 'short' ? formats.month.short : formats.month.long;

var year_format = prompt('Choose a format for the year. (short or long)') == 'short' ? formats.year.short : formats.year.long;

alert('The date is ' + moment().format(month_format + ' ' + day_format + ' ' + year_format));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yeah, this works. I was hoping to find a way to implement it with arrays like I have above that hold the day of the weeks and months.

Comment: @akcode17 Is there a specific reason as to why you would prefer to use arrays? An object is more suitable for this use case, in my opinion.